# How to write a catch all XSL template that also passes all the params?

Tags: templates, xslt, transform, parameter-passing, xslt-2.0

I am writing a template that "extends" templates, but it has some issues.

```
<xsl:template match="*[@condition]" mode="#all">
<xsl:element name="condition">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@condition"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-imports>
  </xsl:apply-imports>
</xsl:element>
```

The problem with this is templates called using `<xsl:apply-imports>` are missing params. 
The list of params are not known since there are many different templates that this template is trying to extend (hence the `mode="#all"`).

Is there a good way around this?

---

Additional example:

Consider two final templates (read-only):

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="mode1">
    <param name="p1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="mode2">
    <param name="p2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

they are called somewhere (read-only):

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="mode1">
    <xsl:with-param name="mode1" select="$mode1"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:apply-templates mode="mode2">
    <xsl:with-param name="mode2" select="$mode2"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

There might be 100s of mode1, mode2, mode3, mode4 ... and the names do not have a pattern.

I would like to have a global template that wraps additional info around the final templates. Something like:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="#all">
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:element>
```

The problem is the above global template does not pass the params to the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that when you call `<xsl:apply-imports>` it doesn't include the parameters passed to the current template, you can use tunnel parameters. In the template you are extending mark your parameters like this:

```
<xsl:param name="foo" tunnel="yes"/>
```

Also, when you pass the parameters:

```
<xsl:with-param name="foo" tunnel="yes"/>
```

I also suggest using `<xsl:next-match>` instead of `<xsl:apply-imports>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is partially the problem. There is also another problem - the name of the param is also unknown, aka, the name="foo" is not known and there are various templates that takes various params. It is not possible to find every templates and list all the params there.

Comment: @Jason: There's no need to declare tunnel parameters in every template, just when you use them.

Comment: I have just added another more complete example. I hope this illustrates what I am looking for. The key is the templates are read-only and the caller files are also read-only. I can only extend the templates somehow.

Answer (score 1):

**You can either use tunnel parameters as suggested by Max Toro, or you could just pass a single parameter**, whose children are the parameters that different templates will need and will recognize.

**Something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pComposite" as="element()*">
   <param for="templateX" name="pA">
    12
   </param>
   <param for="templateY" name="pB">
    Some String
   </param>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="*[@condition]">
  <condition name="{@condition}">
   <xsl:apply-imports>
     <xsl:with-param name="pComposite"
      select="$pComposite"/>
   </xsl:apply-imports>
  </condition>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dimitre. It is helpful. In case there are many templates with many params, do I have to iterate all of them in the pComposite param? I was hoping for params can be passed on to other templates in a more transparent way. - Jason

Comment: @Jason: There is no need for iteration. Every template gets its params with an XPath expression like: `$pComposite/myName`  -- I find this convenient and useful.

Comment: In this case, would I have to modify all other templates and introduce the new parameter pComposite?

Comment: @Jason: Yes -- this is one line per template. The existing `<xsl:param>`'s `select` attribute should be changed/added (almost mechanically) to `$pComposite/respectiveName`.

Comment: this is what I am trying to avoid. I need a global wrapper template so that I don't have to modify all the templates. The templates are provided by 3rd party and they are independently upgradable. I am still trying, reading through the w3c xslt2.0 spec right now.

Comment: I have added a more complete example to illustrate the problem I am facing. Thanks!